# Vectors - Cross Product

Tags: vectors

I was given the vector $v= <1 , 2 , -1>$ and was then asked to calculate $v \times i,\; v \times j,$ and $v \times k$. I know I would use the cross product for this, but is there a relationship between the original vector and $i,j,k $that I am missing?

Comment: what is *? do mean to denote the cross product?

Comment: yes, as like v x i

Comment: I would have guessed "*" might be the "dot" product.

Comment: sorry about the confusion - I meant cross product

Comment: It might help of you think of $\bf {i,j,k}$ as  $\mathbf i = (1,0,0), \mathbf j = (0,1,0), \mathbf k = (0,0,1)$

Comment: thank you - is that just a rule I am supposed to know?

Comment: That is the definition of these principal component vectors.

Answer (score 1):

$\vec v = i+2j-k$

$\vec v \times i = \begin{vmatrix}i&&j&&k\\1&&2&&-1\\1&&0&&0\end{vmatrix} = j-2k$

I assume you can do the others

EDIT:

You should think of $i= [1,0,0],j= [0,1,0]\& \;k = [0,0,1]$. Those are the basic definitions of the unit basis vectors. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector#Cartesian_coordinates)

Answer (score 1):

Vector v can be represented as **1i +2j - 1k**

For cross pdt with **i** you may proceed components wise,

1. Cross pdt of i and **i** (i X i)will result in 0

2.Cross pdt of of 2j  and **i** (2j X i) will result in -2k

3. Cross pdt of -k and i (-k X i) will result in aj where a is magnitude i-e (-1 * 1)

**Represent the results in steps 1,2,3 as a single vector to get the answer**

For the possitve and negative sign of the direction vector(as in case 2, the resultant is negative contrary to the other two cases) you may imagine i to be in place of 12 in the clock, j in place of 4 and k in place of 8.

When the first vector is ai and second is of form bj, for moving from i to j you travel clockwise so the result (a*b)k will be possitive (because you moved clock wise)

If the first vector is j and second is i the resultant vector from the cross pdt. will be in direction of negative z axis as you travel anti clockwise while moving from j to i

Comment: Simply multiply the magnitudes and for direction of the resultant unit vector (i-e possitive or negative) imagine the unit vectors to be placed on a clock....remember that cross pdt. Of two parallel vectors will be zero